# Chart.js / ng2-charts: active chart elements on hover

Tags: angular, charts, ng2-charts

I'm working on a bar chart based on time data (x-axes) and data points (y-axes). If I hover my mouse over one of the chart elements, I would expect that only the chart element that is hovered over become active. However, several chart elements become active.

**Examples:**

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9wCF.png)

[Stackblitz](https://chartjs-ng2-chart.stackblitz.io)

**Options:**

```
{
  "scales": {
    "xAxes": [
      {
        "type": "time",
        "distribution": "linear",
        "time": {
          "tooltipFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
          "unit": "month",
          "stepSize": 1,
          "displayFormats": {
            "month": "MM YYYY"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "yAxes": [
      {
        "scaleLabel": {
          "display": true,
          "labelString": "KEY: Gallon / month"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "responsive": true,
  "legend": {
    "display": true
  },
  "tooltips": {
    "enabled": true
  }
}
```

**Datasets:**
I've added three times the same dataSet:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "x": "2019-07-31T22:00:00.000Z",
      "y": 92
    },
    {
      "x": "2019-06-30T22:00:00.000Z",
      "y": 163
    },
    {
      "x": "2019-05-31T22:00:00.000Z",
      "y": 185.8
    },
    {
      "x": "2019-04-30T22:00:00.000Z",
      "y": 213
    },
    {
      "x": "2019-03-31T22:00:00.000Z",
      "y": 379
    },
    {
      "x": "2019-02-28T23:00:00.000Z",
      "y": 209
    },
    {
      "x": "2019-01-31T23:00:00.000Z",
      "y": 251
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-12-31T23:00:00.000Z",
      "y": 352
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-11-30T23:00:00.000Z",
      "y": 119
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-10-31T23:00:00.000Z",
      "y": 109
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-09-30T22:00:00.000Z",
      "y": 213.6
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-08-31T22:00:00.000Z",
      "y": 220
    }
  ],
  "label": "wmb Coolant",
  "type": "bar",
  "backgroundColor": "rgb(0,61,143,0.2)",
  "borderColor": "rgb(0,61,143)",
  "hoverBackgroundColor": "rgb(0,61,143,0.8)",
  "hoverBorderColor": "rgb(0,61,143)",
  "order": 0
}
```

Is there anything I have to configure in a specific way?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried different combinations of [interactions](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/) and [interaction mode](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/modes.html#interaction-modes) configurations, but could not achieve exactly what you asked. What you described and the image you provided is the expected behavior of a grouped barchart (imo).

However, the configuration I thought provided the best user experience (and I would use in my own apps) is setting `tooltips.mode` to 'index'. When you hover over a stack of bars, all data points in that stack appear in the tooltip.

**Options Object**

```
{
  ...
  tooltips: {
    enabled: true,
    mode: 'index'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I've changed the mode to "index", but this unfortunately not solves the problem I have.

When I hover over a bar chart element, other bar chart elements change their effect too. I would expect, that the hover effect only is applied for the bar chart element I'm hovering.